# Chrome changing HTML ID in advance

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am changing the Id of an HTML image using javascript, but I noticed that chrome is reading the code ahead, and changing the Id's in advance. When I run the exact same code on IE, or even use the f12 deveolper tools on chrome to make the code run line by line, the console logs something different than when I simply run it on chrome.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("apples"));//IE logs html element with Id of apples, chrome logs element with id of oranges 
document.getElementById("imageId1").id = "oranges";//Change ID to oranges
console.log(document.getElementById("oranges"));//Both IE and Chrome log html element with Id of oranges
```

So, if Chrome *is* reading ahead as I suspect, and is changing the Id in advance, how can I make it stop (as it messes with my code).

Comment: provide a complete example, with all of your HTML and javascript.you have not provided enough information for anyone to diagnose this. provide a complete self contained code snippet or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome's console is showing a live log of the element. This is why you see *oranges* instead of *apples*.

Use `console.dir` instead and you will see the id(the value at time of logging) printed next to the element name. But if you open up the object properties you will see the live value of id.

```js
console.dir(document.getElementById("apples"));
document.getElementById("apples").id = "oranges";
console.dir(document.getElementById("oranges"));
```

```html
<img id="apples" />
```

Or put the last two statements in a setTimeout

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("apples"));
//gives chrome the time to log the element
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("apples").id = "oranges";
    console.log(document.getElementById("oranges"));
},100);
```

```html
<img id="apples" />
```

You can also just log the property itself instead of the object

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("apples").id);
document.getElementById("apples").id = "oranges";
console.log(document.getElementById("oranges").id);
```

```html
<img id="apples" />
```